# What is the geometric story behind vector addition when the vectors act simultaneously?

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

In a 2D plane, consider two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. I understand that the net effect of moving along $\vec{u}$, then $\vec{v}$, gives the resultant vector $\vec{u}+\vec{v}$, and the head-to-tail placement of the vectors in this case reflects the order in which the vectors are applied. I also understand why the same resultant vector is achieved when first moving along $\vec{v}$, then $\vec{u}$, since both resultants are the same diagonal of a parallelogram. What I do not understand (geometrically) is why the same resultant is achieved even if the vectors were applied simultaneously, instead of in sequence (which allowed us to build a friendly head-to-tail diagram). If I work with the algebraic/components representation, all of these results can be trivially explained with algebraic properties, but I'm looking to have it make sense with my geometric understanding of vector addition.

The best I've done so far is this: imagine breaking up $\vec{u}$ into $N$ equally sized pieces, where $N$ is huge, and then break up $\vec{v}$ into $N$ equally sized pieces as well. If we mix up these pieces uniformly, and then apply them in sequence, it would approximate "simultaneous" movement along $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, assuming $N$ was big enough. Then, we can use the commutative nature of vector addition we already established to see why the desired resultant is the same.

My explanation is not fully satisfying to me. Is there something I'm missing? Is there an easier way to see why $\vec{a}+\vec{b}$ is equal to what it is in the case the vectors don't "take turns" acting?

Comment: What do you mean by "simultaneously"

Comment: If $\vec{u}$ is 10 mi North, and $\vec{v}$ is 10 mi East, then I understand $\vec{u} + \vec{v}$ as 10 mi North THEN 10 mi East. And I understand $\vec{v} + \vec{u}$ as 10 mi East THEN 10 mi North. I see why the end point is the same, geometrically. But I don't see why it's the same (geometrically) if you move 10 mi East and 10 mi North simultaneously. I know it is, I just can't "see" it since the head-to-tail placement doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: What does ist mean to move 10 mi East and 10 mi North *simultaneously*?  Wouldn't that be moving NE?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing like moving simultaneously. If you think deeply about moving along two vectors simultaneously it means that you are moving along the diagonal of the parallelogram formed by the two vectors (rectangle in your case) also known as **parallelogram rule of vector addition**.
Taking your 10 mi north and 10 mi east example:
It is not possible to move along two vectors simultaneously thus you need to change the direction. Suppose you divide these 10 mi in infinite no. of small distances **dm** then if you move one **dm** along north direction and one **dm** along east direction since it is infinitely small so it would seem like you are just walking on the diagonal of the square of side 10 mi .
Thus you are walking along the two vectors simultaneously.